# Woocommerce permalinks for product variations

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, permalinks

Is there a way I can get pretty permalinks for woocommerce variations.

Currently all the variations can be linked to as https://interiormantra.com.au/product/coloured-glass-bottle-vase-23cm/?attribute_pa_colour=white

However I was wondering if there is a way to remove the ? and have a pretty permalink.

Thanks

Comment: In this case, Woocommerce is passing the product attributes parameters in the url (GET method)… so you can't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

There's a plugin for this, you can create multiple products and can link them together with variation field. This way you get different permalinks for your products.

Only negative point is that plugin is paid :(

Demo:
https://demos.iconicwp.com/woocommerce-linked-variations/product/iphone-x-space-grey-64gb/

Plugin:
https://iconicwp.com/products/woocommerce-linked-variations/